# setPositiveButton(int, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android

> ERROR: /home/gabr0/Escritorio/Andorid/packages/apps/OwlsNest/src/com/aosip/owlsnest/advanced/ScreenStateToggles.java:187.26: The method setPositiveButton(int, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (int, new OnclickListener(){})
>   ERROR: /home/gabr0/Escritorio/Andorid/packages/apps/OwlsNest/src/com/aosip/owlsnest/advanced/ScreenStateToggles.java:187.83: DialogInterface cannot be resolved to a type
>   ERROR: /home/gabr0/Escritorio/Andorid/packages/apps/OwlsNest/src/com/aosip/owlsnest/advanced/ScreenStateToggles.java:188.41: DialogInterface cannot be resolved to a type
>   ERROR: /home/gabr0/Escritorio/Andorid/packages/apps/OwlsNest/src/com/aosip/owlsnest/advanced/ScreenStateToggles.java:195.88: DialogInterface cannot be resolved to a type
>   ERROR: /home/gabr0/Escritorio/Andorid/packages/apps/OwlsNest/src/com/aosip/owlsnest/advanced/ScreenStateToggles.java:196.49: DialogInterface cannot be resolved to a type

The code

```
 if (value == true){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.screen_state_twogtitle)
                        .setMessage(R.string.screen_state_twogmessage)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.screen_state_twogconnect, new DialogInterface.OnclickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_STATE_TWOG, value ? 1 : 0);


                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SCREEN_STATE_SERVICE_UPDATE");
                    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }})
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.screen_state_twogdontconnect,  new DialogInterface.OnclickListener(){
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                            value = !value;
                            }
                        })
                        .show();}return true;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .setPositiveButton(R.string.screen_state_twogconnect/*wrong perameter*/, new 
  DialogInterface.OnclickListener() {
```

the R.string.screen_state_twogconnect is not a string but the reference to the string which is an integer. You can have to put the string in that places like "string".

you can put it like

```
 .setPositiveButton("the value of twogconnect" , new 
  DialogInterface.OnclickListener() {
```

Answer (score 1):

In both your `setPositiveButton()` and `setNegativeButton()` calls, you've tried to use a `DialogInterface.OnclickListener`. The correct name for this class is `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, with a capitalized "Click".